# Drupal 7 Blogapi replacement

Tags: drupal, module, xml-rpc

I am trying to use service like Word or Scribefire to post information to my drupal 7 site.
but after much googling found out that there is a BLogapi  module is being developed but there is no update has anyone tried this and if not is there anyother way that i can do this? pls advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Blog API module](http://drupal.org/project/blogapi) was part of core in Drupal 6 and got broken out in Drupal 7 (in Drupal 8, the Blog module has also been removed from core). As such, it's now being maintained as a contrib module and does not seem to have very high priority, although it appears to have some backing from Acquia, which is a good sign. I don't think there are any other modules which will do this, per se, and unfortunately, in my experience, the Blog API module didn't do everything that I'd want it to do to take an article live and any images were just thrown into the system/files directory (instead of into sub-directories named after the article, which is what I usually do using [IMCE Mkdir](http://drupal.org/project/imce_mkdir) and also doesn't offer support for filling in other fields I consider critical (proper categories, custom fields, meta-tags, etc). In any case, the Drupal 7 version of the Blog API module is being completely rewritten and is not yet ready for real use, though you could help with testing it as the functionality is built up.

I would suggest writing your blog posts in a good standalone HTML editor and saving them (e.g. on your home computer), then copy that content to the body field and customize (upload images and link them in properly, add category tags, metatags, etc.) At least, then, you'll have a backup of the work in case you accidentally lose what you've typed into the body field. And your posts will be better than you'd probably get from using the Blog API (YMMV, but I've yet to find a compatible editor which did everything in ways I was fully happy with) If your use case and expectations are simple, though, you might well be happy with this module, but you should probably not expect it to be very useful for a while.

Comment: Glad to help. I'd be interested to see how Blog API develops and see if some of the shortcomings I perceived with it can be worked around in some simple way, but as it stands now, I find it easiest to just work in a text editor and copy/paste to the server when I think my content is ready, but of course if my content has many images, I need to upload and fix the src= part in each one, but at least they are then uploaded to logical sub-directories...

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting module which you might find useful, for writing in one place (staging server) and pushing your content "live" is [Deployment](http://drupal.org/project/deploy).

This module has some of the community's “big brains” working on it and I think it shows a lot of promise, but is still in development for D7. That said, it's definitely an interesting project and it *might* be what you want (if your primary goal is to work locally and push live when you are finally ready to do so).

Comment: so this deployment module how does this work? i am specifically looking for Word 2007 to my drupal site pushing content..that would be really interesting..tks for the alternate..

Comment: I don't think there is any solution for pushing from Word to a Drupal site. Deployment makes it easier to have a live site and a local staging site, with content pushed from the local site to the live site.